# How can do this function pure

Tags: javascript

I want to **map** an array, returning the same array except `.created` property, that I'm transforming from **milliseconds** to **Date** Object.

```
const posts = data.map((post) => {
    post.created = new Date(post.created); //milliseconds to Date Object
    return post;
})
```

This function do the result that I expected, but I don't like because the function inside is not pure, is mutating the object. **How can be an alternative to do the same with pure function?**

*Thank you so much.*

Comment: I'd think that mutating a (shallow) clone of `post` instead would make this function pure. How you'd do that depends on the type of `post`, AFAIK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this using `Object.assign` ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)) inside the `map`:

```
const posts = data.map((post) => {
    return Object.assign({}, post, { created: new Date(post.created) });
})
```

This essentially clones the original `post` and then overrides the `created` property.

Comment: @zeroflagL Not exactly. My example is a pure function, which is what the OP wanted. :)

Comment: How can a function that changes the input be pure?

Comment: Thanks, forgot to add the empty object as the target. Now it is pure. :)

Answer (score 1):

I would provide both solutions.

#### Clone the array and its objects

```
data.map(post => Object.assign({created: new Date(post.created)},post));
```

The first argument of `Object.assign` is the `target` object. It's also the object that `Object.assign` returns.

#### Modify the existing array

```
for(let post of data){
    post.created = new Date(post.created); 
}
```

This method is, of course, faster and costs less resources since it doesn't need to initialize a new array and its objects then copy all objects' properties like the other does.

The choice is yours. Just make sure you know what you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

You can make copy without copying all of the attributes from the old object:

```
const posts = data.map((post) => { 
    const obj = Object.create(post); 
    obj.created = new Date(post.created); // shadow created with the new value
    return obj;
});
```

In practice it uses JavaScript inheritance scheme so that the new object only has `created` as it's own attribute and the rest is inherited from the original object.